# javascript equivalent of Disable feature in IE6

Tags: javascript, html

I have come across a requirement to disable the drop down items through the following javascript code.

```
function alertselected(selectobj){
 alert(selectobj.selectedIndex)
 if(selectobj.selectedIndex ==1){
    alert('15656');
    document.getElementById("reportFlag").disabled=true;
 }else{
    document.getElementById("reportFlag").disabled=false;
 }
}
```

Can any one suggest how do i implement this feature without using the disable feature.

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_option_disabled.asp
Above link says that disable attribute is not supported in IE.

Please help me other equivalent approach for the same

Answer (score 1):

The `disabled` attribute is defined on the `input` element in the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled) as follows:

> When set for a form control, this boolean attribute disables the control for user input.

It is also defined on the [`option`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#edef-OPTION) element.

---

I would not use w3schools as an authoritative source of information - they are **not** affiliated with w3 (despite the name) and have many inaccuracies (which they don't fix, even when asked) - see http://w3fools.com

Comment: I am not setting through the form control,

Comment: @harigm - did you see the link to the `option` element? The spec defines it there too.